# Speed up SQL queries on a single table with 2GB+

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, view, aggregate

I am running a query on advertising revenues in a very large table in a MYSQL database. It contains many dimensions, e.g. device class, date, advertiser, vertical, creative_size, location, etc. as well as a few metrics like delivered impressions, clicks and revenue.

The table is used to show the advertising performance, so usually grouped by one or two dimensions and filtered by dimensions.

I have put everything in one table to avoid joins and make it as fast as possible, but because of the number of dimensions, esp. advertiser, the table is big, over 2.8Gb already and growing.

I have tried indexing and partitioning, but it is still very slow, so I was thinking about creating a smaller version by grouping the data by a smaller set of dimensions, leaving out the advertiser column, i.e.

```
Select date, creative_size, device_class,ssp,billing_type, location,
       ad_impressions, clicks, revenue
  from ADS
 group by date,creative_size,device_class,ssp,billing_type,location
```

This would reduce the number of lines enormously.

I was trying to use it as a view, but it is not stored permanently, so it takes even longer. How can I create such a table and keep it up to date based on the other table? Do I need to write a script or can I use some built-in MySQL functionality? Is that a feasible approach? I am open to other solutions of course :)

Comment: It would help you get better answers if you read this, especially the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  This question is right on the edge of being too broad for the Stack Overflow format.

Comment: Ollie's is good, but if you need more help, we really need the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the actual queries.  Also check that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is about 600M for such a tiny RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that MySQL's VIEW objects don't help query performance. In the jargon of the trade, they are not "materialized views."

You haven't disclosed to us the actual queries you use or the actual layout of your big table. So specific suggestions aren't really possible.

You have some possible approaches to improving query performance.

1. As you suggest, generate some aggregate tables from your detail tables. You can regenerate them overnight if you are able to work with slightly stale data.
2. If you use particular queries, investigate creating [*compound covering indexes* to accelerate those queries](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727).

Looking at the query in your question.  First of all I guess it should have some SUM items in it, like so. I also changed your mentions of `date` to `DATE(date)` to get just the days, not the dates and times, in the summary. (Maybe that's already done in your table. If so, don't do it again.)

```
Select DATE(date), creative_size, device_class,ssp,billing_type, location,
       SUM(ad_impressions), SUM(clicks), SUM(revenue)
  from ADS
 group by DATE(date),creative_size,device_class,ssp,billing_type,location
```

Second, this one doesn't have any `WHERE` clauses. If you do add `WHERE` clauses, you (almost certainly) need different compound covering indexes. You can read about how to use covering indexes with `WHERE` clauses elsewhere.

Third, this query can be accelerated by a particular compound index: an index on all the columns mentioned in the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` clauses. The columns in the `GROUP BY` clauses should come first in the index, generally in the same order as in the `GROUP BY`.  You would create such an index like this.

```
 CREATE INDEX summary_1 ON ADS 
              (date, creative_size, device_class,ssp,billing_type, location,
               ad_impressions, clicks, revenue);
```

This helps because MySQL's query planner can read through the index sequentially to satisfy your query, without having to follow pointers to your table.

Fourth, you can do

```
CREATE TABLE ad_summary AS
Select date, creative_size, device_class,ssp,billing_type, location,
       SUM(ad_impressions), SUM(clicks), SUM(revenue)
  from ADS
 group by date,creative_size,device_class,ssp,billing_type,location;
```

This is a poor man's materialized view. (If you were using Oracle, you could use their materialized views, which we call *formerly rich man's materialized views.* -- formerly because Oracle is so expensive.)

Fifth, you can date-limit your summary table (if that works in your application). Do that by adding something like this to your query.

```
  WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

This particular `WHERE` clause can use the same compound covering index, because it does a range-scan on `date`, and that column is first in the index.

Here are some general observations about grinding very large tables for you to consider.

- Lots of single-column indexes on tables like yours are generally harmful to performance.  MySQL doesn't exploit multiple indexes in a single table in a single query very well if at all.
- `SELECT *` is *definitely* harmful to performance, especially when you have lots of columns. Instead, enumerate the columns you need.
- Avoid `ORDER BY` clauses in large queries unless you know you need them.
- http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is a great reference on making this stuff work well.

Comment: [_More_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) on summary tables.